# document and refer to a group of defines

Tags: c, doxygen

Especially when wrtiing drivers I often have a group of defines, typically giving meaning to bits in a register

example.

```
#define STATUS_READY (0x01)
#define STATUS_STALL (0x02)
#define STATUS_FAIL  (0x04)
```

...

```
StatusRegister = getStatus();
if( (StatusRegister & STATUS_READY) == STATUS_READY)
{
    DoStuffWhenReady();
}
```

a.s.o.

Is there a way in Doxygen to group these defines into a named group, so they will show up in the define list as a group, and i can refer to them?

eaxmple:

```
/**
 * Return the status of register foo
 *
 * @return status bit for register foo see @ref FooStatusBits for bit defines
 */
int getStatus(void);
```

I tried

```
///@name FooStatusBits
///@{
    #define STATUS_READY (0x00)
    #define STATUS_STALL (0x01)
    #define STATUS_FAIL  (0x02)
///@}
```

Didn't work (also tried with @name inside { })

I tried

```
///@defgroup FooStatusBits Regiser foo status bits
///@{
    #define STATUS_READY (0x00)
    #define STATUS_STALL (0x01)
    #define STATUS_FAIL  (0x02)
///@}
```

Did partially work, but pulls the documentation of those defines out in a separate html file, and they show up in the modules list, both unwanted.

Comment: At leas in this simple case you would be much better off with an enumeration type. This groups such constants together and you could then just document the `enum`.

Comment: Be careful, `(x & 0) == 0` is always true, so `(x & STATUS_READY) != 0` will be always false

Comment: I have always preferred to document constants like these as enum.  Not only does the documentation work better, you can have the added benefit of scope.

Comment: Sorry for loong reply time, thought i get email when replies to my question.
@jens Gustedt I agree on the Enum, but am faced with the task of documenting existing code, that is not too be touched (exept the comments)

Comment: @Eregrith I corrected the example, it was a typo. (note & is a binary or)

Comment: @user816389 Well no, `&` is a binary AND... `|` is a binary or

Comment: @Eregrith Yes of course :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refering to the [documentation](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/commands.html#cmdref), it says that:

> `\ref <name>`: Creates a reference to a named section, subsection, page or anchor.

It does not mention groups, so I think you can't refer to named groups with `ref`. If

A workaround could be creating an anchor with the keyword `anchor`. You have to place this anchor in the `@name` block, then you can freely refer to it:

```
/**@name FooStatusBits
* @anchor FooStatusBits
*/
///@{
    #define STATUS_READY (0x00)
    #define STATUS_STALL (0x01)
    #define STATUS_FAIL  (0x02)
///@}
```

One hint of such this workaround is to have in mind that the name of a group is a string, not a single word, so it won't be taken by doxygen as a link symbol.

Comment: Not the Solution I hoped for, but a quite useful workaround. So i tag is answer as this is the solution I will use.

Comment: Extra tip: If You add `@name Defines` group to the remaining defines not in a group. the layout of the html page start to look quite nice.